# C++ accessing functions in sibling classes having has a relationship

Tags: c++

In C++, I have a class with following three sub classes

1. one Tx module responsible for transmitting the data
2. one Rx module responsible for receiving the data
3. one control block which controls the TX and Rx modules and other things.

I created the main class "top" with "has a" relationship which contains these three modules. Now in TX (or RX) class I need to access some functions from RX(or TX) class and also from control class.
With "Has a" relationship what is the best recommendations to achieve this

Comment: You've presented very little details. Circular references are often a sign of bad design. I would try to move this functionality outside of TX/RX if possible. Perhaps the "control block" should be a "control module". The concept of interfaces/abstract classes may be useful here as well.

Comment: In both Tx and Rx, provide an init() method.  After both are built, 'top' shall call each and pass in the reference (or pointer) to the other sibling.  (This is very similar to 'work/protect siblings' in embedded telcomm transport.)

Comment: Is having an init function to pass the reference/address is a good practice or just a workaround

Comment: Can you show the code you have produced ?  It's too broad otherwise

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach is to initialize a pointer to `Rx` inside `Tx` (or vice versa), and then query it directly if it not `NULL`.